# Describe the Linear span from the following vectors(3). Find the basis and dimension of that linear subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, span

First and foremost, I'm translating my work from French to English so I apologize if I use incorrect terms.

Question: Describe the Linear span from the following vectors. Find the basis and dimension of that linear subspace.

$U = \{(-3,6,-9),(1,-2,3),(6,-12,18)\}$

1. I found that the determinant from the matrix formed with the $3$ vectors and it gave a determinant of $0$, meaning that the vectors are linearly dependent.

I need to find the vector equation using the following system:
\begin{align}
    -3a + b + 6c &= x\\
     6a -2b -12c &= y\\
    -9a +3b +18c &= z
\end{align}
Solving the system, I came with this answer:
$$
    U=\{(x;y;z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 | z + 1.5y = 0\}
$$
I found it weird that the x disappeared, so I tried solving it another way and came with this answer:
$$
    U=\{(x;y;z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 | x-y-z = 0\}
$$
Both answer apparently work and I am totally confused as to which I have to use to find a basis and the dimension... or does it not matter?

If so, does that mean there exists many answers for the basis?
Thank you. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectors in $U$ are all multiples of each other, so they span just a line.

This means (by the rank-nullity theorem) that the solution set to $xu_1+yu_2+zu_3$ is a *two-dimensional* subspace of the $(x,y,z)$-space. That's why you can get two different $(x,y,z)$ combinations that both work. But you should be critical of the *methods* you used to find those two solutions, if both of them failed to tell you that what you got was not the *entire* solution.

(It also seems that you are a bit confused between what is $(a,b,c)$ and what is $(x,y,z)$, which may or may not explain why something went wrong in your solution.